# Extend method for generic List<> types

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

**TL;DL:** simplify `method<returnType, ListType>(this List<ListType>, ...)` to `method<returnType>(this List<anyType>, ...)` for generic Lists

I'm looking to write an extension method that allows me to get the values of all properties "P" within a List of (any type of object)

So far, I got this method to work:

```
public static T[] selectAll<T, U>(this List<U> list, string property)
{
    List<T> r = new List<T>();          // prepare a list of values of the desired type to be returned
    foreach(object o in list)
    {
        Type mt = o.GetType();          // what are we actually dealing with here? (List of what?)   <-- This should be the same as Type U
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(mt.GetProperties());          // Get all properties within that type
        foreach(PropertyInfo p in props)
        {
            if (p.Name == property)                   // Are we looking for this property?
                r.Add((T)p.GetValue(o, null));        // then add it to the list to be returned
        }
    }
    return r.ToArray();
}
```

Because you can't simply have an unknown return type, I understand that it's necessary to indicate the return type in the method call, e.g:

`List<Control> SomeListOfControls =` ...

`string[] s = SomeListOfControls.selectAll<`**string**`, Control>("Text");`

But, since the Type of the items within that list is rather irrelevant for this method, I want to eliminate the Type variable from the equation.
I wish I could simply call

`List<Control> SomeListOfControls =` ...

`string[] s = SomeListOfControls.selectAll<string>("Text");` <-- You know damn well what this List consists of >.<

for example.

But I can't think of a way to do this. 
Even before compiling I can see that

```
public static T[] selectAll<T>(this List<> list, string property)
```

is an `Unexpected use of an unbound generic name` (meaning `List<>`).

And `List<object>` fails to register as an extension for all kinds of `List<?extends object>`, so to speak.

How, if at all possible, can I make this work?

**PS:** It seems like there might be a "native" way (.net or even C# in general) to retrieve a collection of <T> P from a collection that may have properties P of type T - I couldn't figure it out using `select` and all... But if there is: I'd be happy to learn about it :)

Comment: Try using IEnumerable (non-generic). I did a quick test and it seems to work with string[], for example.

Comment: @glenebob Yes, I JUST tried that myself using `IEnumerable<object>`,  which worked. Still looking for bad edge cases to find out how robust it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for non-generic version for parameter - either `IList` or `IEnumerable` would work

```
public static T[] selectAll<T>(this IList list, string property){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, brother... I didn't see that possibility because I didn't have `System.Collections` itself used - thanks for the correct answer. My alternate answer details what had me confused :)

Answer (score 0):

**Aftermath** (what went wrong where)

Although I had imported (`using`) both

```
System.Collections.Generic
```

and

```
System.Collections.Specialized
```

I was not aware that the classes those namespaces are partially inheriting from are in fact in `System.Collections`. I thought I was getting both halves of a cake, whereas I was getting two fillings while missing the crust.

So when ever I tried using an `IEnumerable`, for example, my dear and trusty IDE (Visual Studio 2017) would not accept it without a type indicator `<T>`.

For anybody coming here through Google with the same problem:

**Using both `.Generic` and `.Specialized` will not have you covered**, much of what the collection types draw from is in the parent `System.Collections`.

```
public static T[] selectAll<T>(this IList list, string property)
{
    // ...
}
```

and

```
public static T[] selectAll<T>(this IEnumerable list, string property)
{
    // ...
}
```

may serve you right.

Although, for my case as outlined above,

```
public static T[] selectAll<T>(this IEnumerable<object> list, string property)
{
    // ...
}
```

Worked just as well (whereas `IList<object>` failed to register as an extension of `List<`?`>`

The naming of spaces and concepts can be quite misleading:

I would consider `IList<Type>` to be specialized (by Type), and `IList` generic (Since it's applicable to all `<Type>`s) - but in C# world, it's the other way around: `IList` by itself is considered "non-generic" - the question of generic...ness is approached from the outside (how is it treated in context) rather than the inside (what does (or can) it contain) - something a high-level programmer like me might intuitively get wrong.

**In summary:**

- `System.Collection` consists of more than the sum of its classes
- Intuitively generic collections are called non-generic because the lower-level powers that be said so
- `System.Collections.IEnumerable` seems to apply to all kinds of Lists
- Reading up on official docs is generally useful. (Wait... generally or specifically? Oh, who knows anymore :P )